# Ошибка RubyOnRails приложения при деплое на Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть задача сделать деплой RubyOnRails-приложения на Heroku. 
Локально приложение запускается на localhost:3000.
Делаю пуш на Heroku, все без проблем:

```
...
remote: -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
remote:        Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
remote:        To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
remote:        ruby '2.4.4'
remote:        # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions    for more information.
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> web
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 52.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v8
remote:        https://guarded-castle-23ххх.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/guarded-castle-2ххх0.git
   1ad56dc..280f10b  master -> master
```

Дальше запускаю команду: heroku run rake db:migrate
Результат такой:

```
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ guarded-castle-23xxx... up, run.5032 (Free)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'

...

/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:138:in `local_cache_key'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:74:in `middleware'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:79:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

При попытке открыть приложение с Heroku в браузере через его же интерфейс получаю краш, вот лог:

```
2018-06-14T06:08:11.240625+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: production
2018-06-14T06:08:11.240623+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2018-06-14T06:08:11.240626+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 2
2018-06-14T06:08:11.240628+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Preloading application
2018-06-14T06:08:12.274420+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
2018-06-14T06:08:12.274461+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
2018-06-14T06:08:12.367910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 139
2018-06-14T06:08:12.380797+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-06-14T06:08:13.610527+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=guarded-castle-23xxx.herokuapp.com request_id=6ef07c51-d168-4767-8206-acbd15618786 fwd="213.109.225.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-14T06:08:42.603065+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=guarded-castle-23xxx.herokuapp.com request_id=f6e0da4a-2b8e-4714-8138-6be8274bda3b fwd="213.109.225.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-14T06:18:08.780840+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by user хххххх@gmail.com
2018-06-14T06:18:12.344049+00:00 heroku[run.6601]: Awaiting client
2018-06-14T06:18:12.367947+00:00 heroku[run.6601]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2018-06-14T06:18:12.547802+00:00 heroku[run.6601]: State changed from starting to up
2018-06-14T06:18:18.219866+00:00 heroku[run.6601]: State changed from up to complete
2018-06-14T06:18:18.203570+00:00 heroku[run.6601]: Process exited with status 139
2018-06-14T06:18:40.325835+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=guarded-castle-23xxx.herokuapp.com request_id=49c978d2-11ec-4f27-a879-4fc0204b9d46 fwd="213.109.225.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Добавляю Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
#gem 'pg'
gem 'pg' , '0.17.1'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read    more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'puma', '2.11.1'
end
```

Также файл database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5


development:
  <<: *default
  database: database_name
  username: xxx
  password: 'xxx'

test:
  <<: *default
  database: database_name
  username: xxx
  password: 'xxx'

production:
  <<: *default
  database: database_name
  username: xxx
  password: 'xxx'
```

Помогите разобраться в чем причина краша приложения. 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У вас в продакшне нет гема для работы с БД, потому как гем pg в гемфайле находится в группе development. Верните его в общую группу

Comment: Перенес в gem 'pg' , '0.17.1' в общую группу, закоммитил, запушил, запустил heroku run rake db:migrate, но ничего не изменилось. Приложение не работает на продакшене.

Comment: @StepanIR, добавьте пожалуйста начало бэктрэйса ошибки, которую вы получаете при запуске  rake db:migrate. Всё самое полезное обычно в начале :)

Comment: Добавил начало, раньше его сам не видел, т.к. очень много строчек, 
что значит
    SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Answer (score 0):

Это известная [проблема использования слишком нового Ruby со слишком старым Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27670#issuecomment-329526301). Поскольку вы не указали версию Ruby в `Gemfile`, о чём вас даже предупреждают:

```
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
remote:        To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
remote:        ruby '2.4.4'
remote:        # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions    for more information.
```

...используется версия по умолчанию для Heroku: 2.4.4. А локально у вас, видимо, нечто постарше. 2.3? Проблемы начинаются именно в 2.4, т. к. там свели воедино `Fixnum` и `Bignum` в `Integer`, что сломало совместимость ряда библиотек, в том числе ActiveSupport, в котором и образовался рекурсивный взрыв (обратите внимание на множество *одинаковых* строк в трейсе ближе к поломке).

А ошибка эта была исправлена в **Rails 4.2.8**. Посему, вариантов у вас два, выбирайте:

- Укажите в гемфайле версию Ruby, на которую ориентируетесь
- обновите гем `rails` в гемфайле до 4.2.8 или выше (рекомендую `~> 4.2.8`)

Comment: Действительно, добавил в гемфайл строчку ruby '2.2.3' и приложение поднялось. Но сейчас проблема в том, что на главной странице не отображается все то, что должно отображаться (т.е. то, что  отображается локально). Подскажите куда копать.